# HTS voice is not running on festival version 2.5

Tags: text-to-speech, voice, speech, festival

I have downloaded the hts voices from festival repository and each time its showing
**rateconv: failed to convert from 16000 to 0**

speech_tools containing EST_Wave.cc have this converting method but its getting failed
I tried same thing in festival 2.2 and 2.5 versions but fail to convert
[image]